# in ant :BUILD EXCEPTION

Tags: ant

I am getting some problem while running ant
Here is the details of problem:

```
C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\mdd_install\mc_config\ant\compile\compile.xml:30: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.compilers.CompilerAdapterFactory.getCompiler(CompilerAdapterFactory.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:924)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:757)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:341)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:369)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1216)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1185)
```

I echo java_home and its value is correct
I am running my aplication from jboss and try to execute it, but it is getting the above exception. I put tools.jar in jboss server **lib folder** ,with that it is runnig fine,but it is not correct way.

Comment: The exception isn't lying to you. It's very possible that the JBoss startup script changes JAVA_HOME. You should also show how you're starting Ant: are you using Runtime.exec() or are you calling `Launcher.main()`? And please format your question.

Comment: hi.sorry for format of the question.I am not getting your point.please elabroate it.

Comment: @mum How do u call ant? Is the JAVA_HOME correct prior to calling ant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the case of the path to JAVA_HOME is right. Reopen the window or environment you're running ant from to make sure it's using the updated environment vars.